# Pandas: Edge case on boolean index into empty DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas

I'm using pandas 0.8.1

Creating a non-empty DataFrame:

```
import pandas
blah = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.empty([1, 1]), columns=['A'], index=pandas.DatetimeIndex(['2008-01-01']))
blah[numpy.array([true], bool)]

            A
2008-01-01  0

blah[numpy.array([True], bool)] = 0.0
```

That's all fine, but in the empty case:

```
blah = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.empty([0, 1]), columns=['A'], index=pandas.DatetimeIndex([]))
blah[numpy.array([], bool)]

Empty DataFrame
...

blah[numpy.array([], bool)] = 0.0

Traceback (most recent call last):
...
IndexError: invalid index
```

That's not right, is it?

Comment: What's the bug here? That it raises an Exception as opposed to pass silently?

Comment: There's a few things going on here, confusing your question. 1) I suggest restarting your interpreter, typing your code in again, and sending us what you get. There are typos that need to be cleared up (e.g., true != True). 2) Give us the output of your whole DataFrame, and describe your intended Dataframe. 3) Finally, note you can index the first element of blah with `blah.ix[0,0]`. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but that might be relevant.